# Given a surface, finding how many times the image is covered

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'll give out an example for this case.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x = \cos(u\sec v)\cos v \\ y = \sin(u\sec v)\cos v \\ z = \sin v
\end{bmatrix}$$

Whenever I'm asked how many times the image surface is covered I always follow this procedure:

- I find the inverse function, writing $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x,y,z$.
- For a given set, I find the number of points $u$ and $v$ correspond from the inverse function, which gives me the number of coverings.

Do you think this procedure is correct? (finding the inverse function etc.) What are your opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend your procedure, since inverse functions are not always explicitly available and involve complicated agreements about their domains and ranges.

Instead try to visualize "dynamically" what the given parametric representation is producing. For a full treatment of this problem you would have to indicate the precise $(u,v)$-domain you are considering. If this domain is all of ${\mathbb R}^2$ then it is obvious that your "surface" is covered an infinity of times, since the given function $(u,v)\mapsto{\bf r}(u,v)$ is $2\pi$-periodic in $v$.